# How to check overlap constraints in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

Suppose B and C are both subclass and A is a superclass. B and C can not have same `id` (disjoint)

```
CREATE TABLE a(id integer primary key);
CREATE TABLE b(id integer references a(id));
CREATE TABLE c(id integer references a(id));
insert into a values('1');
insert into a values('2');
insert into b values('1');
insert into c values('2');
```

Could I use a trigger to prevent the same `id` appearing in tables B and C?

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for.  If you are using a trigger to apply your id's, or using the trigger on a table to make sure the id does not already exist, you have a bad design.  Use sequences as specified in the answer.  If you are using triggers to make sue the id value does not exist on any of the three tables, even worse design, and actually will not work.  Again, go with the sequences.  In your insert statements, you are working with integers, do not enclose in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

> "b and c can not have same id"

So you want to enforce a mutually exclusive relationship. In data modelling this is called an arc. [Find out more](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ARC_relationship).

We can implement an arc between tables without triggers by using a `type` column to distinguish the sub-types like this:

```
create table a (
  id integer primary key
  , type varchar2(3) not null check (type in ( 'B', 'C'))
  , constraint a_uk unique (id, type)
);
create table b (
  id integer 
  , type varchar2(3) not null check (type = 'B')
  , constraint b_a_fk foreign key (id, type) references a (id, type)
);
create table b (
  id integer 
  , type varchar2(3) not null check (type = 'C')
  , constraint c_a_fk foreign key (id, type) references a (id, type)
);
```

The super-type table has a unique key in addition to its primary key; this provides a reference point for foreign keys on the sub-type tables. We still keep the primary key to insure uniqueness of `id`.

The sub-type tables have a redundant instance of the `type` column, redundant because it contains a fixed value. But this is necessary to reference the two columns of the compound unique key (and not the primary key, as is more usual).

This combination of keys ensures that if the super-type table has a record `id=1, type='B'` there can be no record in sub-type table C where `id=1`.

Comment: Nice answer.  Had not run across this arc relationship before.

Comment: @CamilleDell'Ava - true. My assumption is that a question asking about enforcing a data model construct implies a malleable data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE multi_table_seq;

INSERT INTO A VALUE(1);
INSERT INTO A VALUE(2);
INSERT INTO B VALUE(multi_table_seq.NEXTVAL());  -- Will insert 1 in table B
INSERT INTO C VALUE(multi_table_seq.NEXTVAL());  -- Will insert 2 in table C
...
```

With trigger:

```
-- Table B
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_BEFORE_INSERT_B  -- Trigger name
BEFORE INSERT                       -- When trigger is fire
ON A                                -- Table name
DECLARE
  v_id            NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_id := multi_table_seq.NEXTVAL();
  BEGIN
     SELECT TRUE FROM C WHERE id = v_id;
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, v_id || ' already exists in table C');
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND -- Do nothing if not found
  END;
END;
```

And same trigger for table C who check if id exists in table B

Comment: This doesn't work because the ID in tables B and C are foreign keys to A.ID. Your trigger will break that relationship.

Comment: You right, I fix my code. Btw, question was about solving issue with trigger, not by changing data structure...

Comment: Now you have the same problem as @sandeep - triggers like this don't scale and don't work in multi-user environments :)

Answer (score 0):

Design wise this is not good but we can do it using the below snippet. You can create a similar trigger on table b

```
CREATE TABLE a(id integer primary key);
CREATE TABLE b(id integer references a(id));
CREATE TABLE c(id integer references a(id));

create or replace  trigger table_c_trigger before insert on c for each row
declare
counter number:=0;
begin
select count(*) into counter from b where id=:new.id;
if counter<>0 then
raise_application_error(-20001, 'values cant overlap between c and b');
end if;
end;

insert into a values('1');
insert into a values('2');
insert into b values('1');
insert into b values('2');
insert into c values('2');
```

Comment: Triggers like this don't scale and also will fail to enforce rules in multi-user environments.